# It is possible to run cmd's commands using C++ in QT app?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, sailfish-os

I am making a QT mobile app (Sailfish Os, it's made with Linux) and I need to run some processes with commands which could be run only with command line/terminal.
Can I do this using QT/C++ code or I am talking about something impossible? :)

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344807/read-qprocess-output-to-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17344807/read-qprocess-output-to-string)

Comment: have a look at [`QProcess`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you can run Linux commands in Qt app by using QProcess. This is a small example:

```
QProcess *system_command = new QProcess();
system_command->start("/bin/bash");
system_command->waitForFinished(500);
system_command->write("ls -a\n");
```

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: (sorry for the off) About [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27887342): the probability of the acceptance of your edit suggestions could be hugely improved if you read and keep [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/advice-for-non-native-english-speakers/291370#291370).